# OpenERP Create Method returns Access Denied error

Tags: php, odoo

Hello I am new in OpenERP and when I am trying to insert a record in Open ERP using Create Method in PHP it returns error Access denied. 
***Following is my Code for Insert:***

```
<?php

include('xmlrpc.inc');

$arrayVal = array(
'name'=>new xmlrpcval('Fabien Pinckaers', "string") ,
'vat'=>new xmlrpcval('BE477472701' , "string")
);

$client = new xmlrpc_client("http://107.23.27.60:8069/xmlrpc/object");

$msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("test_sys", "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("1", "int"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("demo", "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("res.partner", "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval("create", "string"));
$msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($arrayVal, "struct"));

$resp = $client->send($msg);

if ($resp->faultCode())

echo 'Error: '.$resp->faultString();

else

echo 'Partner '.$resp->value()->scalarval().' created !';

?>
```

in above code test_sys is database name and 1 is my user id. 
***Following is the Output:***

```
xmlrpcresp Object
(
[val] => 0
[valtyp] => 
[errno] => -1
[errstr] => Access denied.
[payload] => 
[hdrs] => Array
    (
        [content-type] => text/xml
        [content-length] => 286
        [server] => Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3
        [date] => Thu, 10 Jan 2013 04:29:55 GMT
    )

[_cookies] => Array
    (
    )

[content_type] => text/xml
[raw_data] => HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 286
Server: Werkzeug/0.8.3 Python/2.7.3
Date: Thu, 10 Jan 2013 04:29:55 GMT

faultCode
AccessDenied


faultString
Access denied.

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check for permission for the user which you are using to create `res.partner` record.

I think you are using `demo` user and `demo` user dont have permission to create `res.partner` record.

If you want to add record with `demo` user, please add `create` permission in demo's permissions.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works, i was using demo user and second thing where i was passing parameter value demo it should be user password not user name. @Kumar

Answer (score 0):

I have error like this 
because user or password wrong